# Query and transpose a long row of data Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have rows of data with a lot of columns, example:

`Date=Team2:Date   Date        Exercise 1   Reps   Weight  Team    Exercise 2    Reps   Weight`

```
9/18/2019        9/18/2019   chinup       10        2       2    situp         10     3
```

I want to pull the data in another sheet as follows:

```
Date=Team2:Date    Exercises    Reps    Weight   Team
   9/18/2019       chinup       10      2        2

   9/18/2019       situp        10      3        2
```

I tried a combination of query and transpose but am not getting the result I want. Is this possible at all?

Comment: is the orange considered as team 2 and green as team 3? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/autxg.png

Comment: where do you see orange and green? there is currently only 1 team, you can ignore that. i will be adding more teams later

Comment: @player0 thanks, am i allowed a followup question? if so: how would i only select the rows that have team 1?

Comment: this is very unfriendly format what you got because you have only 1 column per row with Team (is this intended or not yet finished?). lets say if you would have Team column after every Weight column then formula would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!C2:F; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!G2:J; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!K2:N}, 
 "where Col5 = 1
  order by Col1", 0))`

Comment: And if thats not possible, i cant do it?

Comment: well in that case you need just: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!C2:F}, "where Col5 = 1 order by Col1", 0))`

Comment: not working :( but i will just use that sheet to query only team 1 to yet another sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if AddTraining sheet is like:

[image: 0]

then you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!C2:E; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!G2:I; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!J2:L; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!N2:P; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!R2:T; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!U2:W; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!X2:Z; 
 AddTraining!A2:A, AddTraining!AA2:AC}, 
 "where Col2 is not null
  order by Col1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vsK2rT_EkTBBC0NTMlBknqcEbivS3rdcOvJpjr71v_8/edit#gid=1041693218)